# telnetd accepts only one connection

Tags: unix, telnet, freebsd, bsd

I have got telnet server running on a bsd target. I want to connect to this target from multiple other machines. Surprisingly it does not allow more connections.

I checked why and found it is not listening(listen) in a loop. So, I kinda fixed it. But I was wondering is there any specific reason why telnetd code is kept with single connection at a time? (I am allowed to connect to telnetd server from only one client for a particular port.)

(I know telnet is not a safe option. But I am having just fun on small embedded platform and getting things working is more imp than security at this moment.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet is supposed to be launched by [inetd](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd). You need to configure inetd to do the listening for you.

The wikipedia article that I linked to explains how to do that.